# Is it possible to parse Scala with JDT

Tags: scala, eclipse-jdt

I am using JDT to get ASTs and type resolvers for Java sources in Eclipse, is there a way to achieve the same for Scala sources in Scala projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to parse *Scala* with *Java* Development Tools. Scala and Java are two completely different languages. They have different syntax, different semantics, different type systems.

Comment: Java and Scala are different languages, however as I've understood the Eclipse plugins for Scala have been able to reuse a large part of the underlying JDT framework, and secondly, a new Scala project in Eclipse does have a Java Nature in addition to the Scala Nature... If the Scala plugins for Eclipse can use JDT, how can I make use of it also?

Comment: Scala projects that have some folders with Java nature will use JDT for the Java portion. The Scala presentation compiler does not use the JDT, although it may use some internal libraries.